# Issues with Odoo v13 UID/API

Tags: python, api, odoo

Having an issue with the api for Odoo v13. I am able to get the server info but for some reason the uid is not being returned

```
 import xmlrpc.client

url ="localhost:8069"
db = "pnv3"
username = "test"
password = "test"

common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
print(common.version())

uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, url)
print(uid)
```

getting this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Web Content/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 11, in <module>
    uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, url)
  File "C:\Users\Web Content\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1112, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "C:\Users\Web Content\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1452, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "C:\Users\Web Content\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1154, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "C:\Users\Web Content\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1170, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(resp)
  File "C:\Users\Web Content\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1342, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "C:\Users\Web Content\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 656, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 1: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 59, in __new__\n    return cls.registries[db_name]\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper\n    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__\n    a = self.d[obj].me\nKeyError: \'pnv3\'\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 63, in xmlrpc_2\n    response = self._xmlrpc(service)\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 43, in _xmlrpc\n    result = dispatch_rpc(service, method, params)\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 138, in dispatch_rpc\n    result = dispatch(method, params)\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/common.py", line 61, in dispatch\n    return g[exp_method_name](*params)\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/common.py", line 30, in exp_authenticate\n    res_users = odoo.registry(db)[\'res.users\']\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/__init__.py", line 104, in registry\n    return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 61, in __new__\n    return cls.new(db_name)\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 73, in new\n    registry.init(db_name)\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 141, in init\n    with closing(self.cursor()) as cr:\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 492, in cursor\n    return self._db.cursor()\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/sql_db.py", line 649, in cursor\n    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/sql_db.py", line 186, in __init__\n    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/sql_db.py", line 532, in _locked\n    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/sql_db.py", line 600, in borrow\n    **connection_info)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect\n    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)\npsycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "pnv3" does not exist\n\n'>

Process finished with exit cod
```

1

Databse does exist, have triple checked my password, not sure what else to do at this point.

Comment: Show please also your config  "odoo.sh shell" import odoo.tools .... tools.config...

Comment: Check the owner of the database, and when you go to database management does the database appear,  did you create the database using odoo UI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url to Odoo server should include protocol part "http://" in the beginning. Strange that you get the version info at all. What do you get as output for the version?

Also you pass the url as the last parameter to `authenticate` method and this is not required. This should still not give the error you received.

Try your code with these two fixes and report if this helps:

```
import xmlrpc.client

url ="http://localhost:8069"
db = "pnv3"
username = "test"
password = "test"

common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
print(common.version())

uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
print(uid)
```

Identical code works on my machine...

Comment: I am unsure why, but after re-writing my code it works and returns the UID. Might have been a tab issue? Unsure, but thank you !